# How to monitor incoming and outgoing network bytes from express & socket.io servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, monitoring

I have an express server which also contains socket.io on it. I want to know how many bytes going outside and coming inside on each clients' requests including HTTP and Socket (WSS). I'm looking for a solution with open source technologies.

I found many tutorials online to get the read bytes inside the `createServer` method but here I'm not using this method since I use `express.js`. Please refer to my below code and assist me.

We use Nginx for our production server.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

http.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Server is running at 0.0.0.0:8080`))
```

Comment: with "client" you mean source ip or how you define what a client is ?

Comment: Server and client

Comment: That donst answer my question, you need to tell how you identify what a "client" is. Not in the meaning of http/socket.io client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture socket.io stats too you need to got on the tcp layer.
A tcp socket in node js has handy properties for these: `bytesRead` & `bytesWritten`: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_bytesread

When a client close the socket, use these to calculate the whole amount of transferred stuff.

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const stats = new Map();

setInterval(() => {
    console.log("stats", stats);
}, 3000)

const web = http.createServer(app);

web.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new connection")

    if (!stats[socket.remoteAddress]) {
        stats[socket.remoteAddress] = {
            receive: 0,
            transmit: 0
        };
    }

    socket.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Save stats")
        stats[socket.remoteAddress].receive += socket.bytesRead;
        stats[socket.remoteAddress].transmit += socket.bytesWritten;
    });
});

web.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log("Running")
});

const io = require("socket.io")(web);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on("timestamp", (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    let html = '<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>';
    html += '<script>';
    html += '   const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:8080");';
    html += '   setInterval(() => {socket.emit("timestamp", Date.now())}, 1000)';
    html += '</script>';

    res.end(html);
});
```

Note that this measure everything, incl. http header & other overhead.
I don't know what happens when the socket is not closed properly (timeout, etc.)

That's not "fail save", you need to add error handling and timeout stuff so you don't miss any transferred byte(s).

If you need anything to be changed or it doesn't work like expected, let me know!

---

Updated answer based on the comment/"chat"

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const stats = new Map();

setInterval(() => {
    console.log("stats", stats);
}, 3000)



const web = http.createServer(app);


web.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log("Running")
});


const io = require("socket.io")(web);



app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const { socket } = req;

    if (!stats[socket.remoteAddress]) {
        stats[socket.remoteAddress] = {
            receive: 0,
            transmit: 0
        };
    }

    socket.once("close", () => {
        console.log("Save stats")
        stats[socket.remoteAddress].receive += socket.bytesRead;
        stats[socket.remoteAddress].transmit += socket.bytesWritten;
    });

    res.end("Hello World");

});
```

This count only http request on the route `/`, no websockets just plain http.

Comment: web.on("connection", (socket) => { " from this how can I get the endpoint that client access for

Comment: You mean the url ? you cant. this on the tcp layer, tcp dosnt understand the http protocol. A http message must be first parsed

Comment: HTTP or WSS, which is more data consuming ?

Comment: On http you must send the complete http message, incl. headers etc. over and over for every request. For websockets message, once a ws connection is etablished, only the payload and a few other bytes are transmited, because its use the underlying tcp socket. so ws is more "bandwidth" friendly

Comment: Thank you, I need to know  the received and read bytes of this `app.get('/', (req, res) => {`

Comment: @AmalaAmala For http & websocket ? or just inside the express route ?

Comment: inside the express route

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223288/discussion-between-marc-and-amala-amala).